# Objects.filter(id__in=[ids]) "Field 'id' expected a number but got 1,2" JavaScript and Django

Tags: javascript, django, forms

Im tring to set categories for my post without a form, with javascript

template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" accept=".mp4" style="text-align: center;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p style="color: gray; padding-top: 20px;">or</p>
    <select name="" id="ms" multiple="multiple">
    {% for category in categories%}
            <!-- <option type="checkbox" value="{{category}}">{{category}}</option> -->
            <input id="category" class="category" catid="{{category.id}}" type="checkbox" value="{{category.id}}">{{category}}</input>
            {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title">
    <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" placeholder="Tags: Please separate by comma ','">
    <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Please describe your video..."></textarea>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select file to upload.</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" accept=".mp4" class="form-control" id="fileupload" placeholder="Select file">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">     
</form>
```

js:

```
    var id_categories = []; 
    var category = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
    for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
        id_categories.push(category[i].value)
      }
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('categories', id_categories)
```

in my views:

```
categories_1 = Category.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
 categories = request.POST['categories']
 FileFolder.save()
 tag_list = taggit.utils._parse_tags(tags)
 FileFolder.tags.add(*tag_list)
 categories_post = Category.objects.filter(id__in=[categories])
            if categories_post:
                for category in categories_post:
                    FileFolder.categories.add(category)
return render(request, 'main/create_post.html', {'categories': categories_1})
```

It returns :

> ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got '3,4'.

but when i type manually [3,4], it works, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **categories = request.POST['categories']** casting to list?
Probably u have list of string ['3,4']

```
categories = parse_ids(request.POST['categories'])
```

```
def parse_ids(ids: str):
    result = []
    for id in ids.split(','):
        try:
            result.append(int(id))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return result
```

Comment: so how do i fix that? is there a problem with my javascript?

Comment: problems not in JS, params passing over HTTP casting to string and u need convert it back. Check code in my comment